# Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) / Uninitalised value was created by a heap allocation (realloc)

Tags: c, valgrind, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to transpose a (non-square) matrix in C (in-place).

`****mats` is a pointer to a dynamically alloc'd 3d array

`**ll` is a pointer to a dynamically alloc'd array in which I keep the number of lines for each matrix

`**lc` is a pointer to a dynamically alloc'd array in which I keep the number of columns for each matrix

```
253 void transpose_mat(int ****mats, int **ll, int **lc, int k) {
254  int max_dim = (*lc)[k];
255  if ((*ll)[k] >= (*lc)[k])
256    max_dim = (*ll)[k];
257
258  (*mats)[k] = realloc((*mats)[k], max_dim * sizeof(***mats));
259  for (int i = 0; i < max_dim; ++i)
260    (*mats)[k][i] = realloc((*mats)[k][i], max_dim * sizeof(****mats));
261
262  for (int i = 0; i < max_dim; ++i) {
263    for (int j = i + 1; j < max_dim; ++j) {
264      int tmp = (*mats)[k][i][j];
265      (*mats)[k][i][j] = (*mats)[k][j][i];
266      (*mats)[k][j][i] = tmp;
267    }
268  }
269
270  int tmp = (*lc)[k];
271  (*lc)[k] = (*ll)[k];
272  (*ll)[k] = tmp;
273
274  (*mats)[k] = realloc((*mats)[k], (*ll)[k] * sizeof(***mats));
275  for (int i = 0; i < (*ll)[k]; ++i) {
276    (*mats)[k][i] = realloc((*mats)[k][i], (*lc)[k] * sizeof(****mats));
277  }
278}
```

Valgrind output

```
1 2
1 2 

----transpose_mat
==18654== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==18654==    at 0x484DC80: realloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==18654==    by 0x10A67A: transpose_mat (my_octave.c:260)
==18654==    by 0x10B1CC: main (my_octave.c:436)
==18654==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==18654==    at 0x484DCD3: realloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==18654==    by 0x10A60C: transpose_mat (my_octave.c:258)
==18654==    by 0x10B1CC: main (my_octave.c:436)
==18654== 
2 1
1 
2 

---- free_k_matrix
==18654== 
==18654== HEAP SUMMARY:
==18654==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18654==   total heap usage: 14 allocs, 14 frees, 5,212 bytes allocated
==18654== 
==18654== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==18654== 
==18654== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==18654== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

What am I missing here?

I tried initialising the values after I realloc the memory for mats but I end up with even more errors and a segmentation fault.

Comment: Being a [three star programmer](https://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer) is nothing to strive for. Adding more indirections doesn't make things better. ***Return*** values instead of emulating pass by reference. Though in this case, why are you emulating pass by reference in the first place? I really don't really see any meaning for it. You don't assign to `*mats` itself anywhere. Same with `ll` and `lc`, why are they pointers to pointers?

Comment: Transposing 2D non-square matrix is more complex. Read [Non-square transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_matrix_transposition#Non-square_matrices:_Following_the_cycles)

Comment: As for your problem, please try to create a [mre] to show us. How do you call this function? What are you passing for arguments? How are those arguments initialized? Considering my previous comment with too many pointers, I'm guessing there's some misunderstanding somewhere.

Comment: You use `(*X)[k]` everywhere. Maybe rather than passing pointer to 3 arrays and `k`. Pass a pointer to k-th element of each array. This approach would let you replace each `(*X)[k]` with `(*X)` or even `*X`.

Comment: *I am trying to transpose a (non-square) matrix in C (in-place).*  You **can't** transpose your matrix in place, because it's not a 2-dimensional matrix in the first place.  It's a one-dimensional array of pointers to multiple individual one-dimensional arrays of values.  The array of pointers has a number of elements equal to the number of rows in the matrix, and each individual array of values that constitutes a row has a number of values that matches the number of columns.  You simply can not transpose the rows and columns in-place as the data structure is fixed to the original dimensions.

Comment: Remember `malloc()` and `realloc()` allocate, but *Do Not* initialize values. You either need to set all allocated pointers `NULL` manually, or call `memset()` and set all bytes zero in your allocated blocks. For initial allocations you can use `calloc()` which will allocate and set all bytes zero so in the case you do not explicitly assign to each element/pointer the value is initialized. You must still set new memory allocated with `realloc()` to zero if you don't explicitly assign to each new element/pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
==18654== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
```

That line tells you you have an uninitialized value.

```
==18654==    at 0x484DC80: realloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
```

That line tells you Valgrind found use of the uninitialized value in the `realloc` routine.

```
==18654==    by 0x10A67A: transpose_mat (my_octave.c:260)
```

The line tells you `realloc` was called from line 260 in `my_octave.c`, which is `(*mats)[k][i] = realloc((*mats)[k][i], max_dim * sizeof(****mats));`.

So you know one of the arguments to `realloc` was not initialized. `max_dim` was used before, so the fact there is no earlier complaint indicates we can conclude it was initialized. `sizeof(****mats)` is a constant. So it must be that `(*mats)[k][i]` was not initialized.

Initialize it.